# Rails 4 Drying up Controller CRUD using Concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am in the process of Drying up my Rails 4 app. I have noticed that I type out the exact same code quite a lot and that it might be better to place this in a concern. I am just not exactly sure how to do this, as I suspect it might require some Meta Code.

I would like to place (ex.) this "create" method in a controller concern called CrudGenerator:

```
def create
   if @contact_us.validate(params[:contact_us])
      @contact_us.save
      flash[:success] = t :create_success_flash, class_object: "Contact Us"
      respond_with(@contact_us, :location => new_contact_path)
    else
      render :new
    end
end
```

Now this will nee to accept 2 params if moved to a concern i.e. "contact_us" and "new_contact_path" as these params will be unique each time this concern is included. These are the only sections of this code that will change.

I have tried to use define_method to generate the below code, but I am not 100% certain.

Any advice on how to generate the below code in a concern and make it part of my ContactUsController ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can move the code in a concern like this:

```
def create
  resource_class.new(permitted_resource_params)

  if resource.save
    redirect_to some_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

And then include this concern in the controllers you want to add this functionality to. To load the resource, you can do it in a before_action call and load resource using params[:controller_name].capitalize.constantize... I hope you get the point